# How to pass the same ListEventPublisher and ReadWriteLock to CollectionList and child EventLists in GlazedLists?

Tags: java, glazedlists

Person class:

```
public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

House class:

```
public class House {

    private final EventList<Person> residents = new BasicEventList<>();

    public void addResident(Person resident) {
        residents.add(resident);
    }

    public EventList<Person> getResidents() {
        return residents;
    }
}
```

init code:

```
EventList<House> houses = new BasicEventList<>();

CollectionList<House, Person> allResidents = new CollectionList<>(houses, new CollectionList.Model<House, Person>() {

    @Override
    public List<Person> getChildren(House parent) {
        return parent.getResidents();
    }
});

jTable.setModel(GlazedListsSwing.eventTableModel(allResidents, new String[]{"name", "age"}, new String[]{"Name", "Age"}, new boolean[]{false, false}));

House firstHouse = new House();
houses.add(firstHouse);
firstHouse.addResident(new Person("John", 18));

House secondHouse = new House();
houses.add(secondHouse);
secondHouse.addResident(new Person("Mary", 44));
secondHouse.addResident(new Person("Alisa", 6));
```

So there are houses, which contain lists of residents. The table should show all residents from all the houses.

New residents can be added to a house at any time, so the table should be able to reflect the changes. This is why `EventList` is an obvious choice to store the residents in one house.

However, GlazedLists requires that the `CollectionList` and the resident `EventList`s all use the same `ListEventPublisher` and `ReadWriteLock`.

### The question

How am I supposed to pass the same `ListEventPublisher` and `ReadWriteLock` to both the `CollectionList` and the resident `EventList`s of every `House` instance, considering that

- the table should update every time I remove or add a resident to a house?
- instances of `House` class may be created both **before** and **after** the creation of the `CollectionList` itself and they **all** must be valid entries to it?

Note that the second criterion makes it impossible to just get the `Publisher` and `Lock` from the `CollectionList` and pass them to the constructors of new `House`s. (because the houses may be created before the list itself)

Are there maybe other workarounds than sharing the `Publisher` and `Lock`?

---

*Related question:* [How to deal with GlazedLists's PluggableList requirement for shared publisher and lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263681/how-to-deal-with-glazedlistss-pluggablelist-requirement-for-shared-publisher-an)

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation about it, but this approach works for sharing `ListEventPublisher` and `ReadWriteLock` between lists:

```
public static final ListEventPublisher PUBLISHER = ListEventAssembler.createListEventPublisher();
public static final ReadWriteLock LOCK = LockFactory.DEFAULT.createReadWriteLock();
```

Put those variables somewhere and then pass them to every constructor of new `EventList`s

I found this by looking at GlazedLists' source code and saw them creating their locks and publishers that way. Unfortunately I don't know whether this approach has any drawbacks or whether it is a correct way at all.